# PC is not recognizing Ethernet cable

Tags: ethernet, desktop-computer

all,
My fairly new-ish PC is not recognizing my Ethernet cable as being there. I have tried reaching out to my ISP, and using a different cable, but it still did not recognize the cable. I troubleshooted for about an hour, trying things like verifying the cable worked (it did), and using a different port. I even reinstalled windows. I attempted to update the drivers but it said I did not have an Ethernet port or something like that, and when I went in to device manager, it did not show "Ethernet" under network adapters. After trying everything possible, I even booted up Ubuntu, and, still, no cable detected. Is it a motherboard thing? I am running an **ASUS P8z77-M motherboard**, an **i3-3225** and a **1050 ti**.

Comment: Sounds like onboard network interface is malfunctioning. // When booted to Ubuntu, please provide the output of `lspci` and `sudo dmesg | grep eth`. You can copy the text from any terminal window and paste it here inside a code block. // Also make sure to check in BIOS/UEFI setup that the network interface is not disabled, this is sometimes possible.

Comment: There is usually a "load BIOS defaults" or "load BIOS safe settings" option in the BIOS. The manual to look that up is available from Asus: [www.asus.com/supportonly/p8z77m/helpdesk_manual/](https://www.asus.com/supportonly/p8z77m/helpdesk_manual/).

Comment: Have you enabled the device within BIOS? Have you updated the BIOS? Have you downloaded and installed the lan driver from the Asus web site - assuming Windows <= v10? That new-ish mb is over 10 years old, hardly new-ish.

Answer (score 0):

> I went in to device manager, it did not show "Ethernet" under network
> adapters.

The Ethernet NIC is normally part of the motherboard and soldered in. If not (if separate) try re-seating it.

Otherwise get a USB Ethernet Adapter and see if that works. It likely will.

If not, then the motherboard might have issues. See if you can get a replacement board.

Comment: Will I still need to get one if I get a new motherboard? I am going to install an a320m-a pro motherboard and a Ryzen 5 4500

Comment: Try a USB adapter and see if that works.  They are good down the line for testing.

Comment: I think you have the conclusion backwards. If the USB adapter works, then there's likely something wrong with the MoBo. If it doesn't, then the issue may lie anywhere… USB Ethernet shares basically no logic with onboard Ethernet, so as long as USB is working, USB Ethernet should be working too.

Comment: I merely suggest both things. Different order and not backwards